# array_map causes server to crash

Tags: php, windows, apache, codeigniter, crash

Following code is craching my apache web server. When i remove database query from `parse_service_rows()`, then apache doesn't crash.

I also tried to remove WHERE clause from the query with no help.

My code looks like this:

```
public function tab($tab_name = '') {
    /*
     * CODE TO GET ROWS
     */
    $service['rows'] = array_map(array($this, 'parse_service_rows'), $service['rows']);
}

private function parse_service_rows($row) {

    // This query causes apache to crash
    $order = $this->db->get_where('services', array(
            'service_user_id' => $this->user->get('user_id'),
            'service_firm_id' => $this->firm->id,
            'service_type' => $row['type'],
            'service_object_id' => $row['object_id']
    ), 1)->row_array();

    return $row;
}
```

However, it worked when i tried using `foreach` instead of `array_map`:

```
foreach ($service['rows'] as $key => $row) {
    $service['rows'][$key] = $this->parse_service_rows($row);
}
```

Windows error window gave following information:

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: httpd.exe
  Application Version:  2.4.2.0
  Application Timestamp:    4fafa3e6
  Fault Module Name:    php5ts.dll
  Fault Module Version: 5.4.4.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4fd8f85c
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000713cd
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1061
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: the first advice I'd suggest is to make sure you're on the latest release of PHP. The crash message says you're on 5.4.4. Try upgrading to the latest version (5.4.10); it's possible that there's a known bug that's been fixed. If that doesn't fix it, you may need to report the crash to the PHP devs. Creating a minimal test case that demonstrates the problem in the smallest possible amount of code will help in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You should check your IIS PHP error logs, you should be able to find this through your IIS admin in the PHP configuration and read it from there.

Make sure that your PHP log level is at least E_ALL and error_reporting is turned on, if this is a dev server you should probably have display_errors on too. These are all options in your PHP.ini which you can also edit from your IIS admin console.

If that is no help here are some areas which you should have a look at;

- Call $this->user->get('user_id') before the query and set the result to an instance of a variable. This will show you if the user class is instantiated and if there are any problems with scope on the get function in the user class.
- Also call this outside of the get_where too, $this->firm->id, id may not be a public property which will also cause PHP to fatal.

Answer (score 0):

@Kristian Have you tried declaring parse_service_rows() before tab()? I recall reading somewhere that there can be problems using a callback if the callback function is declared after the calling function.